# Change host protocol from http to https with kafka

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ssl, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have a problem with kafka when I work with http protocol kafka run with me without any problem

but after upgrading the protocol from http to https

after upgrade it all services return the same error

```
2021-10-28 23:16:26.367  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 (/206.189.178.228:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-28 23:18:02.623  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=groupId] Connection to node 1 (/206.189.178.228:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

in producer and consumer i dont know what happens or if this error appeared from SSL

but i did not change any configuration about Kafka

this is my kafak.yml file

```
                                                                                   kafka.yml                                                                                               
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.0
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - food_default
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://206.189.178.228:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://206.189.178.228:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      - food_default

networks:
  food_default:
    external: true
```

and this is service config this config existing in each other service

```
    version: '2'
services:
  food-order-service:
    image: altshiftcreative/food-app-order-service:v1.5
    environment:
      # - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
      - MANAGEMENT_METRICS_EXPORT_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED=false
      - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://food-mysql:3306/food_db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createD>
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_PROVIDER_OIDC_ISSUER_URI=https://shopbia.shop/auth/realms/jhipster
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_CLIENT_ID=internal
      - SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET=internal
      # - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30 # gives time for other services to boot before the application
      - KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    networks:
      - food_default
networks:
  food_default:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka isn't an HTTP protocol, so your problem has nothing to do with that

You've set `KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092`

> i did not change any configuration about Kafka

I think you did. That IP address is not the default of anything. To revert to expected behavior within the same Docker network, you need to set

```
LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

Unclear where you're getting the IP address from, but if you want to expose the Docker container to an external network in that subnet, then you will need other settings